# crontab - how to create in Terminal?

Tags: php, mac-osx, cron, terminal

I'm trying to run a scheduled task on my shared Linux server using the crontab via Terminal on my Mac.

I can login to my ssh OK, and can view directories etc with ease.

I try and create/edit my crontab by using...

***crontab -e***

But i get the response

***no crontab for [username] - using an empty one***

So trying to then add my line to set my schedule up, and Terminal just doesn't seem to respond.

**10 * * * * /home/username/www/myphpfile.php**

Any clues what on earth I'm doing wrong? Or a link to a clear step-by-step tutorial?

I have checked with the webhost that this is supported, it's just undocumented!

All I want to do is run a php script every so often through the day (to check for updates to an XML file).

Comment: What do you mean, "Terminal just doesn't seem to respond"? Are you not presented with a text editor in which to specify your cron jobs?

Answer (score 7):

I'm betting the $EDITOR variable is set to vi(m).

If you press `i` to go to interactive mode are you then able to enter your crontab?

If so after you are done entering your cron entry, press `escape` then type `:wq<enter>` to save your changes.

Also, learning vi(m) is a good thing check out: http://acs.ucsd.edu/info/vi_tutorial.shtml for a beginner's tutorial.

Comment: great, i'll give this a try. it's not something i ever thought i'd use, so it's completely alien to me. I'll let you know how I get on

Answer (score 6):

try to set EDITOR environment variable, for example doing:

```
EDITOR=nano
export EDITOR
```

Comment: While Zepher's correct that it's the default vi editor Shuvalov is spot on about changing the default editor.  Try his suggestion in one line: export EDITOR=nano

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is that you don't call the PHP interpreter at all. Use this instead:

```
// Assuming your PHP executable resides under /usr/local/php5/bin
10 * * * * /usr/local/php5/bin/php /home/username/www/myphpfile.php
```

Good luck.

Comment: Your mistake is that you forget about the `#!` line. Use it and `chmod +x` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of two possibilities.
1. There is a problem with cron
2. There is a problem with php from the command line

1. Try a simpler command like touch or copy to make sure the cron is working.
2. Is the php command line interface installed on your hosting service? If so, then maybe you need to review your code to use the [CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) effectively

Hope this helps